# Google cloud dataproc cluster created with an environment.yaml with a jupyter resource but environment not available as a jupyter kernel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

I have created a new dataproc cluster with a specific `environment.yaml`. Here is the command that I have used to create that cluster:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create dataproc-testing1 
--enable-component-gateway 
--bucket my-test-bucket 
--region us-central1 --zone us-central1-c 
--master-machine-type n1-standard-2 
--master-boot-disk-size 32 
--num-workers 3 
--worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 
--worker-boot-disk-size 32 
--num-secondary-workers 3 
--preemptible-worker-boot-disk-type 
--preemptible-worker-boot-disk-size 32 
--num-preemptible-worker-local-ssds 0 
--image-version 2.0-ubuntu18 
--properties dataproc:conda.env.config.uri=gs://my-test-bucket/environment.yaml 
--optional-components JUPYTER 
--scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' 
--project my-project
```

This successfully creates the cluster.

I have been able to ssh into the master and the executor nodes and they all have an environment `pyspark` that is created with the `environment.yaml` that I specified in the cluster creation command above. All the dependencies are there and python version is also 3.9.7.

After SSH into the worker or master nodes and running `python --version` gives me `Python 3.9.7`

running `conda env list` gives me

```
#
base                     /opt/conda/miniconda3
pyspark               *  /opt/conda/miniconda3/envs/pyspark
```

Hence, the environment activated is `pyspark`.

I can deactivate this environment with `conda deactivate` and then the `base` environment is activated and there `python --version` results in `Python 3.8.12`

So far everything is as I expect.

Now, I ran the jupyter notebook from the web interfaces tab in the cluster console and the problem is:

It has just 'PySpark' (note this is not the same as pyspark), 'Python3', 'spylon-kernel`, 'R' kernels available. 'R' is for R and 'spylon-kernel' is for scala.

I activate 'PySpark' kernel and run

```
import sys
sys.version
```

and the output is

`'3.8.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 12 2021, 21:59:51) \n[GCC 9.4.0]'`

I activate 'Python 3' kernel and run

```
import sys
sys.version
```

and the output is
`'3.8.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 12 2021, 21:59:51) \n[GCC 9.4.0]'`

In both these kernels none of the packages from `environment.yaml` are available.

In conclusion, I cannot access the `pyspark` environment created by `environment.yaml`.

Can you please help me access the `pyspark` environment created by `environment.yaml`?

Comment: Can you include the contents of `environment.yaml` so it can be reproduced by the community?

Answer (score 0):

Dataproc launches Jupyter notebook from the root/base environment and the user specified environment is not leveraged there. This is currently not supported by Dataproc.